# Ways to declare in C++ a 2D Array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am struggling to understand the code below, I understand that t is a multidimensional character variable ( 3 row and 3 columns), and p is a pointer or array of pointers, the array of pointers shouldn't be declared as:

```
int **p[3][3];
p= new int*[3]
```

instead of `*p = (char *)t;` Can someone help me to understand the meaning of this declaration?.. thanks in advance

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
        char   t[3][3], *p = (char *)t;

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            *p++ = 'a' + i;
        cout << t[1][1];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Throw the pointer-infested code away and use `std::vector<int>` with a size of N * M.

Comment: What do you think it's doing? And is this something from a textbook or given from a class?

Answer (score 1):

char t[3][3] allocates 9 chars in memory, something like:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Next you let the pointer p point to  the first allocated char ( *p = (char * )t

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
*p
```

Knowing there are 9 allocated chars, you can now move the pointer forward with the statement *p++, so after first  *p++

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
   *p
```

Then you insert the char 'a'+i into that memory location

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[ ][a][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
   *p

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[ ][a][b][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
      *p
```

and so on...

Note operator precedence is important, ++ (postfix) has higher precedence than * (inderection), so first the pointer is incremented by one (++), and then the inderection gives 'access' to the allocated memory, if you prefer to be more explicit about it, you can use *(p++) instead.

Answer (score 0):

whats happening is that it's declaring the variable p as having the same pointer as your 2D array t. That way it can access it without requiring nested forloops.

'graphically' the contents would be accessed something like this:

pointer in question.

```
 T
->1 2 3 
  4 5 6
  7 8 9

 P
->1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this

```
char   t[3][3];
```

then pointer to its first element can be declared like

```
char ( *p )[3] = t;
```

That is the pointer `p` points to an object of type `char[3]`. If to increase the pointer `++p` then the value in `p` will be increased by the value equal to `sizeof( char[3] )` that is `p` will point to the second "row" of the array.

The value stored in `p` after this declaration

```
char ( *p )[3] = t;
```

is equal to the value of the expression `&t[0][0]`. The difference is the type of the objects pointed to by these pointers.

Thus you can write for example

```
char *p2 = reinterpret_cast<char *>( p );
```

So `p2` and `p`  have the same value but increasing the pointer `p2` moves it "right" to point to the second character of the array while increasing the pointer `p` moves it "right" to point at once to the second "row" of the array.

So you can reinterpret the pointer `p` as a pointer of type `chsr *` to traverse the array character by character.

You can write either using C casting

```
char *p2 = (char *)t;
```

or using C++ casting

```
char *p2 = reinterpret_cast<char *>( t );
```